# question regarding hyphenated phrase

Tags: word-usage

I've seen so many instances of using hypenated "year-old"  phrases that way , "singular subject pronoun + hyphenated phsase+noun", i.e

"*I'm a **18-year old boy*** and I'm dating with a girl 8 years older than me"
"She's a 15-year-old, pretty girl"

But I've never come across a plural pronoun used along with it, like:

"We're 30-year-old females" or "They are 60-year-old retirees" thus I'd want to know if it's wrong to use plural pronoun in such a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine to use those `hyphenated phrases` such as *30-year-old* with a plural pronoun. There isn't a rule against this.

For more context, the `hyphenated phrase` in the `hyphenated phrase + noun` pattern that you've noticed is a [**compound adjective**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier). The words that are hyphenated together function as a single adjective.

For example:

*The **London-based** biographer, John Smiles, writes about **lesser-known** artists of the 20th century.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mattliu, what about "pronoun +hyphenated phrase" a pattern without a noun following that modifying phrase, like  "I'm a 20-year-old" or "They're 60-year-olds" ? Is that also norm?

Comment: Hyphenating compound adjectives when they follow a noun is not normal. According to GrammarBook.com, ["When a compound adjective follows a noun, a hyphen is usually not necessary."](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp) (refer to Rule 1, and note the exception for "dictionary compounds").